# Solve : No. Coins = 165 | Cost Of Coins = 555 | Denominations = 2 , 5 . Find No. Of Coins Each

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Linear equation in one variable:

I Need To Solve This:

No. Coins = 165 | Cost Of Coins = 555 | Denominations = 2 , 5 . Find No. Of Coins Each Denomination. I Tried A lot But couldn't solve it. Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x$ = number of coins with value 2 and $y$ = number of coins with value 5.

Then, construct the following linear equations:

$x + y = 165$ (total # of coins)
$2x + 5y = 555$ (total worth of coins)

You can then solve the equation for obtain $x$ and $y$.

Edit: if you want one variable, just construct it this way:

$2(x)+5(165-x)=555$, you can see that i have just eliminated y from the two equations above

Comment: Could You Please Explain More Briefly . And Please Write Down The Steps Also . Thankyou Very Much !

Comment: Do you want me to explain it using 1 variable or 2?

Comment: One variable. Please

Comment: To form $2(x)+5(165−x)=555$, you should let x represent the number of coins with value 2. Then, you know the number of coins with value 5 is $165-x$, since there are 165 coins total. Then, the total value of coins can be represented by 2(value of each coin)*x(number of coins) and 5(165-x), which sums to equal 555.

Answer (score 0):

$$2(x)+5(165-x)=555\\
2x+825-5x=555\\
-3x+825=555\\
-3x=555-825\\
-3x=-270\\
3x=270\\
X=270/3
x=90$$
Denominations of $2$ is $90$
Denominations of $5$ is $55$